# User/password less authorization flow for product demonstration

Tags: authentication, auth0, auth0-lock

i have been using auth0 for a little while now and currently thinking through a use case of our application which seems to break the basic patterns of authorization flows.

we will display our product at a few trade fairs in the near future and plan to give potential customers access to our application so they can judge its features on their own. we want to make the onboarding as quick and easy as possible and want to postpone registration and login procedures to a later stage.

i thought about giving out demo-codes printed on cards to interested people, to still restrict access, and also link metadata to it, like the name of the trade fair and other useful information. users could login in using this demo-code or scan a qr-code which resolves to a link to our application with the demo-code embedded.

which authorization flow would suit my needs, if at all?
i thought of Resource Owner Password Grant which should generate an access-token and could set a demo-scope so our api can deny requests to resources not permitted by this scope.
but this still would require a user-password combination sent to the auth0-api and assumes a user is already registered.

an other option would be to send the signup code to our backend, verify it, and then generate an access token and a temporary user account and send the code back to client.
but i could not find a scenario in the docs which comes close to this procedure.

is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't directly suggest a Resource Owner Password Grant for this use case.

I personally would recommend having them complete the sign up through the user/password workflow. This gives you the ability to follow up with their submitted emails or link accounts or craft custom email campaigns. I hope this helps you in your quest!

Comment: thats exactly what im doing now. thanks for the quick reply. 
i pass the code in a the app url, and will resolve it after the redirect from auth0.